# How to access the properties of an instance of a class from another file

Tags: python, module

I have a game with different files. In my enemy file, I am trying to have a function that adds an item to the player's inventory. I don't know how to change the players inventory from my other file.

I have already linked my enemy file to my player file, but i can't access the instance of player.
If i redefine a new instance of player than the progress will restart every time the user collects something. Would it be easier to recode my whole program?

Here is my code file https://repl.it/@MineBrick/Life-RPG

Main.py

```
    from player import Player
    from Enemy import Enemy

    player = Player()
    enemy = Enemy()
    player.test()
    enemy.add_to_inventory()
    print(player.inventory)
```

Player.py

```
    class Player:

        def __init__(self):

            self.inventory = ['Dirt']

        def test(self):
            print('test')
```

Enemy.py

```
    from player import Player

    class Enemy:

        def __init__(self):
            Player.test()

        def add_to_inventory(self):
            Player.inventory.append('glass')
```

When I run the code the players inventory doesn't change.

Comment: Hi Hugo, welcome to stackoverflow. To get a helpful answer to your question, please **include the code in your question** using the formatted code feature (i.e., just indent 4 spaces). Links to code elsewhere have a way of going dead, which makes the question useless for others; so this goes against site policy.

Comment: But I can see already that the problem is, your code is trying to call methods on the class itself, e.g. `Player.test()`. You should be working with the instances of the class.

Comment: Ok, Sorry. I will put my code in future questions. I am new to stack overflow. Is there a way to change the properties of an instance of a class not defined in the same file? Sorry for not putting my code on the question.

Comment: Yes there is, you can access it wherever it is. Can't answer right now but someone else will probably beat me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify an instance, your code needs to know about it. Start by modifying `Enemy.add_to_inventory()` to take an argument, and call it with the player instance you want to modify. E.g.:

```
def add_to_inventory(self, other):
    other.inventory.append('glass')
```

Then, in `main.py`:

```
player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()
enemy.add_to_inventory(player)
```